# What does this syntax means ["@metadata"] = new Dictionary<string, object> : is it .net syntax for dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

What ["@metadata"] means is it .NET syntax ? :

https://dzone.com/articles/answer-what-does-this-code-do

```
    var doc = new Dictionary<string,object>
{
    ["@metadata"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["@id"] = "users/1"
    }
    ["Name"] = "Oren"
};
Console.WriteLine(doc["Name"]);
```

Comment: "@metadata" isn't anything special here, just a string key defined in the dictionary that points to some object. You could define the keys to a `var a = new Dictionary<string,object> { ["a"] = new Object(), ["b"] = new Object() }` just the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's part of C# syntax - using the [new indexer initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244132/c-sharp-6-0-new-feature-dictionary-initializers) available in C#6.